# Volatile instance java

Tags: java, volatile

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос: имеется инстанс синглтона класса SomeClass.

Нужно ли помечать volatile коллекцию clients?
Нужно ли помечать volatile переменные внутри класса Client?

```
public class SomeClass {

    private static volatile SomeClass instance;

    private /*volatile*/ ConcurrentHashMap<String,Client> clients = new   ConcurrentHashMap<String,Client>();

public static SomeClass getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (SomeClass.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new SomeClass();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: А причём тут `clients`?

`instance` надо помечать как `volatile`, см. раздел «Under the new Java Memory Model» в [этой статье](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Если инстанс класса помечен как volatile, нужно ли помечать переменные внутри класса volatile ?

Comment: @druum: Это независимые вещи.

Нет универсального рецепта (потому что если бы был, язык бы сам ставил нужные атрибуты, и не заставлял бы вас). Чего вы хотите добиться этим кодом?

Comment: Различные потоки будут обращаться к этому классу и работать с коллекцией clients.